# My anchor buttons seem to go up a pixel or two on hover

Tags: css

I have a bunch of inline buttons made using anchor tags and CSS. I am making them so that on hover the main text shrinks in size and some subtext displays underneath. For some reason when I do that my button gets out of line with the other buttons and things just don't look right. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="day-picker">
    <a href="#" data-day="0" class="dayChange button">
        <span class="day">Wednesday</span>
        <span class="date">January 27th, 2016</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-day="1" class="dayChange button selected">
        <span class="day">Thursday</span>
        <span class="date">January 28th, 2016</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-day="2" class="dayChange button">
        <span class="day">Friday</span>
        <span class="date">January 29th, 2016</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-day="3" class="dayChange button">
        <span class="day">Saturday</span>
        <span class="date">January 30th, 2016</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  font: 300 18px HelveticaNeue;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 35px; }
  @media (max-width: 47.9em) {
    .button {
      width: 80%; } }
  .button:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-animation-name: button-hover;
            animation-name: button-hover;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
  .button.on-white {
    border-color: #00aeef;
    color: #00aeef; }
    .button.on-white:hover {
      -webkit-animation-name: button-hover-on-white;
              animation-name: button-hover-on-white; }

.selector {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;
  background: url(/images/agenda-bg.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }
  .selector .button {
    border: 2px solid #00aeef;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #00aeef;
    min-width: 223px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: none;
            animation: none; }
    .selector .button.selected {
      background-color: #00aeef;
      color: #FFF; }
    .selector .button .day {
      display: block;
      font-size: 22px; }
    .selector .button .date {
      display: none;
      font-size: 8px; }
    .selector .button.selected, .selector .button:hover {
      text-decoration: none; }
      .selector .button.selected .day, .selector .button:hover .day {
        font-size: 14px; }
      .selector .button.selected .date, .selector .button:hover .date {
        display: block; }
```

the full code with scss is on my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qbjw3pe/1/)

Comment: Seriously?  It takes all of this code to reproduce the problem?  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon I don't see why it's an issue to post my original code. I even provided a fiddle for you that reproduces the issue

Comment: The more code you have that's not relevant to the problem, the longer it takes to sort through the problem.  That's why we require an [MCVE], emphasis on the *minimal*.  Providing Sass instead of the compiled CSS is not reducing the problem to the smallest number of parts.

Comment: @mascaliente Many times I have found my problem while minimizing my problem code before posting. It's easier for those trying to help you if you have less code.

Comment: I would suggest setting the height of the button explicitly and positioning the text absolutely inside. That way the button would not bounce on hover

Answer (score 0):

The reason your buttons move when you hover is that your button height is not set, so it shrinks and expands with its content.

When you change the font size, your button height is smaller (even though you add the other line).

You can fix this in a couple of ways.

The easiest and most reliable (cross-browser, cross-platform) is to give it a set height:

```
.button{
    ...
    height: 48px;
}
```

but this a lot of scaling issues and isn't very responsive.

Another option is to adjust your font size(s) until they don't move, this will likely give you poor cross-anything support.

If you're only targeting newer browsers you could give `vw`, `vh`, and `vmin` a try. They size things based on the width, height, and smaller of the two of the viewport respectively. For example, `10vw` is 10% of the viewport's width.